# JavaScript array elements weirdness

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

This is my first question here.

I have an AJAX returning JSON string, and after function.done, going through:

```
var arData = [];
$.each(response, function(key, value) {
     var temp = [value[0], value[1]];
    arData.push(temp);
    //console.log(temp);
});
console.log(arData);
```

When I print the var temp, the result is quite normal, something like ["BUFFER STOK", 497206627].
But, when I printout the arData variable, the resulting console log is as follows:

[image: resulting array]

How is that that a series of 2 dimensional arrays shows up as 4 in length, with element 0, 1, and 3?

Edit: This is the log of the response object:
[resulting response log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/117qi.png)

*****UPDATE*****

I'm trying to re-word my question.
I'm using ajax to get json data, in pairs: [["data 1", int value 1],["data 2", int value 2],...].
From this data, I intend to create an javascript array with the same value, by using arData.push(["data 1", int value 1]);, for each pair of the json data.

This is my original code:

```
        var arData = [];
        $.ajax({
          cache: false,
          type: 'get',
          url: 'dtsearch4.php',
          data: {type : 2},
          dataType: 'json',
          async: false
        })
        .done(function(response){ 
          $.each(response, function(key, value) {
             $.each(v,function(key, value){
                  //var temp = [value[0], value[1]];
                  arData.push([value[0], value[1]]);
              });
          });
```

However, the resulting array is something like this:

`v[Array[2], Array[2],[Array[2],...]
 v0: Array[4]
  0: "APBD-I"
  1: 302462864
  3: NaN
  length: 4
  __proto__: Array[0]
 v1: Array[4]
 v2: Array[4]`

=> What's with array[4], and element number 0, 1 and 3? No number 2?

While what I want is an array with 2 elements:

`v[Array[2], Array[2],[Array[2],...]
 v0: Array[2]
  0: "APBD-I"
  1: 302462864
  length: 2
  __proto__: Array[0]
 v1: Array[2]
 v2: Array[2]`

Comment: Can you post sample values for `response`?

Comment: I edit the question to include the response.

Comment: what is coming in response. (Dont show me image)

Comment: array, if i print it as text, the result is standard json array: [["APBD-I",302462864],["APBD-II",616363007.68],["BUFFER STOK",...

Comment: Edit your question and mention full response you are getting and what output you want

Comment: i can not solve your question untill i does not get exact response what you getting. i can just give you idea. check my answer.

Comment: @Monty: Hi, the response from json is already correct. I already posted the excerpt of the resulting json array above.

Comment: Why don't you convert your json response to array by `var arr = $.map(response, function(el) { return el });`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to run each loop two times.

```
$.each(v, function(v_key, v_value) {
     $.each(v_key,function(key, value){
          arData.push([value[0], value[1]]);
      });
});

1st loop will take the values like v0, v1, v2. 
second loop will take the values of v0 like 0,1,3,length,__proto__
```

Comment: Thanks, @Monty. Yes, need to have two loops.

Answer (score 1):

Normally its working fine,

```
 <html>
    <head>
    <script>
    function callthis(){
    var arData = [];
    {
        var value=[];
         value[0]="vasim";
         value[1]="vanzara";
         var temp = [value[0], value[1]];
        arData.push(temp);
        //console.log(temp);
    }
    console.log(arData);
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="button" onclick="callthis()" value="Click me">
    </body>
    </html>
```

You can use JavaScript instead of Jquery for call service,
http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/ajaxgetpost.shtml

Answer (score -1):

In this code, jQuery will call your callback function for each elements in the `response` object. `temp`'s lifetime exists only until the end of that function. So, you're only seeing an array with length 2 in the `console.log(temp)` call because it doesn't have its previous value.

```
$.each(response, function(key, value) {
    var temp = [value[0], value[1]];
    arData.push(temp);
    //console.log(temp);
});
```

Comment: Not sure I follow. I know that temp lifetime is only within the scope. However, arData is declared outside of the scope. Shouldn;t the data inside temp be transfered into arData?

Comment: `arData` gets the value of `temp` append to it by the call to `arData.push(temp);`

Comment: Not working. I removed the temp, changed into arData.push([value[0], value[1]]);, but the resulting array is still the same.

Comment: I don't think you understand what the code is doing, you're pushing an array with 2 values onto an array for each time your callback is called. What is the confusion? It's what your code is supposed to do.

Comment: Yes, I believe that's what I'm aiming at. My intended result for arData is something like [ [value1, value2], [value1, value2], etc. ]